# How do I set a version of vim as default?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, clipboard

I am running Ubuntu and have the current situation. The version of vim that opens a file in the terminal has +clipboard enabled. The version that opens a file in a new terminal window when I open it in the GUI or in the pane one gets with the one-key search using the "Windows" key does not have +clipboard. It thus requires an annoying workaround to find a textfile and copy one line through the GUI.

How can I see what versions of Vim I have and configure it so that the one that opens is the good one with +clipboard?

Comment: Does Ubuntu have the "alternatives" command?

Comment: No, but I was prompted to install galternatives. This brings up a window showing me a table, "vim | priority" with entries "basic | 30" and "gtk | 50" and "nox | 40"; there is a radio button selector, and "nox" is selected.

Comment: Try selecting the gtk version.

Comment: I did this on seeing it and it seems to work, but forgot to report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to use is usually:

```
update-alternatives --config vim
```

On some systems it's just `alternatives`. And some systems can have a GUI installed called `galternatives`.

Counter-intuitively the version of vim to select to get the +clipboard feature in a terminal is (one of) the installed GUI version(s) of vim, such as `gtk`.